# What is the slimy fluid from the throat called?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

What is the slimy fluid from the throat called? It's quite clear, not green like mucus. Especially when you're crying, the fluid from your eyes flows down to your nose and throat, and when you spit, it can't be spit easily, but it runs down from your mouth and dangles from there like a long string of saliva.

**PS:**  Here are some images:

[image][image]

As you can see in the images, the fluid is as clear as normal saliva, not as colored as phlegm or mucus, but it's much slimier/oozier. There's an dependent word for this in my language. I wonder if that's the case in English.

Comment: ... ... Phlegm?

Comment: snot, or phlegm.

Comment: In common use, *phlegm* is simply thick *mucus*, and the color is not necessarily determined.

Comment: Those pictures are just of _drool_ which is a word for saliva running out of the mouth.

Answer (score 3):

The word is [**mucus**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mucus). The condition OP is describing is most likely [post-nasal drip](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-nasal_drip).

When it's not thick and difficult to clear like the OP describes, it's just saliva.

[Phlegm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlegm) would more accurately describe the green mucus that OP stated he is not looking for.

Refer to the "Distinction between mucus and phlegm" section of the [Phlegm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlegm) wiki entry.

**Edit based on OP's new information and pictures:**

The pictures show [saliva](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/saliva) or [mucus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mucus)

In English the world mucus does *not* imply that it is not clear. If it is not clear (green or yellow for example) then it is most likely [Phlegm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlegm).

Since the OP desires something thick and difficult to clear, [mucus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mucus) is the word.

Answer (score 2):

As nouns, both [**slaver** (meaning #2)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slaver?s=t) and [**drivel**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drivel?s=t) mean the “saliva coming/flowing from the mouth” and as verbs, they both describe the action of letting it come/flow from the mouth.

(from *Dictionary[dot]com*)

Answer (score 0):

**Phlegm** might be the word you are looking for. (It is technically also a type of mucus - mucus isn't always green.)